# Gradle - Help Dynamically setting revision for Ivy Publish

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, ivy

I am trying to create an Ivy Publication in a subproject with a dynamic revision based upon the version property of the root project which is also set dynamically. So far, the revision is always unspecified and I cannot find a way to set the revision.

I'm new to using Gradle so I'm hoping there is a simple solution I am unaware of. BuildVersion sets the version of the root project. It is getting run but nothing I've tried has set the revision with it. Here is the subproject script I am using. I'm not including any of the things I've tried that haven't worked.

```
apply plugin: 'ivy-publish'

task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
     from sourceSets.main.java
     classifier "source"
}

publish.dependsOn rootProject.buildVersion

publishing {
     repositories {
         ivy {
             url "${rootProject.buildDir}/repo"
             layout 'ivy'
         }
     }
     publications {
         ivy(IvyPublication) {
             organisation 'com.test'
             module 'test'
             revision rootProject.version
             from components.java
             artifact(sourceJar) {
                 type "source"
                 conf "default"
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer *per se*, but I don't have the rep to comment!!

Been working on something similar myself.  My setup is slightly different in that I use Jenkins to run Gradle and trigger deployment of Ivy-format artifacts to Artifactory.  Anyway, I found that the Jenkins plugin uses project.version as the revision so have been setting that within Gradle.

Guessing I'm as new as yourself to this, but just in case it helps you...

**Update:**
Given the comments, the following will allow you to defer the setting of the ivy revision until the execution phase:

```
tasks.create(name: 'preTask') { 
  doLast { 
    // put execution phase code here 
  }
}

tasks.create(name: 'Task') {
  dependsOn preTask
  publishing.publications.ivy.revision rootProject.version
}
```

Comment: My problem is I think (if I"m understanding what Gradle is doing correctly) it parses revision during the initialization phase but the buildVersion doesn't run until the execution phase so the revision isn't getting set. This causes it to always use a revision of 'unspecified' which is my issue. I'm starting to wonder if there is a solution.

Comment: If that's the case then you can use this pattern I found:
`tasks.create(name: 'preTask') {
    doLast {
      // put execution phase code here
    }
}

tasks.create(name: 'Task') {
  dependsOn preTask
  publishing.publications.ivy.revision rootProject.version
}`

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much!If you make this your answer I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Glad it worked - answer updated to reflect the detail...  Though to be clear, I don't think the dependsOn is definitely necessary - guessing you might be able to just run your assignment of revision in a `doLast` block

Comment: That's what I did. I was able to set the revision in a doLast block in my setIvyVersion task (which corresponds to your 'Task' task. Thanks!